# media field type ignores directory

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-field, form-fields-types

I'using a xml formsource (<field name="media" ... />) in a subform for a custom field.

The form is working but my directory path is completely ignored. E.g. directory="mitglieder/attachments/105/10". The directory is correct but the media manager always jumps to the top level (images).

Has something changed in the parameters?

Even with the orginal Joomla media field there is the possibility to specify a directory, but this is also ignored. Even the parameter query directory is missing under joomls 4.3.2.

```
<field name="media" type="media" types="images,documents,audios,videos" directory="mitglieder/attachments/105/10" preview="true" preview_width="176" preview_height="99" label="Media" />
```

The first time you call it, the directory assignment works. If you then change the directory in the media manager modal and call it again, the directory is ignored.

Comment: Could you post more details of your XML form? I've tried it out with a form field of type="media" and setting the directory="..." attribute works fine.